# Why does order matter when using GetTempPath/GetTempFileName?

Tags: delphi

I am troubleshooting some code that is crashing one application. The crash is happening later in application after his code. Maybe memory leak or something similar? I trace it back to the following function:

```
function GetTempFileName: String;
const
  DOC_REGISTER_PREFIX = 'DR';
var
  NameBuffer: array[0..MAX_PATH] of char;
  PathBuffer: array[0..MAX_PATH] of char;
begin
   FillChar(NameBuffer, MAX_PATH, 0);
   FillChar(PathBuffer, MAX_PATH, 0);
   GetTempPath(SizeOf(PathBuffer), PathBuffer);
   Windows.GetTempFileName(PathBuffer, DOC_REGISTER_PREFIX, 0, NameBuffer);
   Result := NameBuffer;
end;
```

The functions works and it gets back a temporary filename but it makes the application to crash for some reason after going up to the caller functions. After some testing and comparing with other similar functions online, I found out that if I change the order between PathBuffer and NameBuffer when using GetTempPath and GetTempFileName, everything works as expected.

```
function GetTempFileName: String;
const
  DOC_REGISTER_PREFIX = 'DR';
var
  NameBuffer: array[0..MAX_PATH] of char;
  PathBuffer: array[0..MAX_PATH] of char;
begin
   FillChar(NameBuffer, MAX_PATH, 0);
   FillChar(PathBuffer, MAX_PATH, 0);
   GetTempPath(SizeOf(NameBuffer), NameBuffer);
   Windows.GetTempFileName(NameBuffer, DOC_REGISTER_PREFIX, 0, PathBuffer);
   Result := PathBuffer;
end;
```

Is there any explanation for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely a buffer overflow. If you are using Delphi 2009+, `char` is 2-byte `WideChar`, not 1-byte `AnsiChar`, in which case `FillChar()` fills only 1/2 of the buffer (it fills bytes, not characters, despite its name), but more importantly `SizeOf()` would pass the wrong size to `GetTempPath()`, allowing it to write more chars than you have allocated space for.  Use `Length()` instead. `GetTempPath()` wants the number of chars, not the number of bytes.

You don't need `FillChar()` at all, and you should pay attention to the return values of the API functions.

Try this:

```pascal
function GetTempFileName: String;
const
  DOC_REGISTER_PREFIX = 'DR';
var
  NameBuffer: array[0..MAX_PATH-1] of char;
  PathBuffer: array[0..MAX_PATH-1] of char;
  Size: DWORD;
begin
  Result := '';
  Size := Windows.GetTempPath(Length(PathBuffer), PathBuffer);
  if (Size = 0) or (Size > Length(PathBuffer)) then Exit;
  if (Windows.GetTempFileName(PathBuffer, DOC_REGISTER_PREFIX, 0, NameBuffer) = 0) then Exit;
  Result := NameBuffer;
end;
```

Answer (score -3):

Acording to documentation for GefTempFileName lpPathName string cannot be longer than MAX_PATH-14 characters or GetTempFileName will fail.

But in your example you are passing string that is MAX_PATH long.

Comment: No. That's not what it says. It says that they string cannot be that long. But you are interpreting that as the array being that long. It's the length of the string that is passed, as determined by the location of the null terminator.

Comment: The documentation says that if the length of the folder path is greater than MAX_PATH-14 then GetTempFileName() fails, since it won't have enough room to store the generated filename on the end of the path. That has nothing to do with the length of the array that receives the folder path from GetTempPath(). The real path length can be up to MAX_PATH and GetTempPath() will succeed, but GetTempFileName() will fail. You would still be able to create files in the folder, just not with GetTempFileName().